# PDO Column Variable LiKE query QUOTES

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

PDO with MySQL; PHP v. 5.2.14

I have a search form with a text box for user input and radio buttons to choose to search either by author or title.  The ouput will eventually be paginated.

I am new to PDO and am still absorbing the basics.  So I would appreciate knowing if I am on the right track.  I had gotten the basic SQL down so things work  but now I want to put a variable as the column.  I have learned that PDO does not accept table or column names as parameters.  So I have tried the following:

EDITED with Corrections AND Added Variation on Binding Parameters

```
try {

if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    echo '<pre>', print_r ($_POST, TRUE), '</pre>';

$selected_radio = $_POST['text_search'];

if ($selected_radio == 'author') {
   $_SESSION['where_field'] = 'author';    
}
    else if ($selected_radio == 'title') {
      $_SESSION['where_field'] = 'title';
    }
}

 if (!empty($_POST['search_term'])){
    $_SESSION['search_term'] =   filter_var($_POST['search_term'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     }else {
        echo "please enter a search term.";
    }

echo "search term: " . $_SESSION['search_term'] . "<br />";

// Find out how many items are in the table
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num_books from t_books where ". 
     $_SESSION['where_field'] ." LIKE :search_term';  
$prep = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$num = $prep->execute(array(':search_term' => '%'.$_SESSION['search_term']. '%'));

 var_dump($prep);
  echo "<br />";
   if ($num) {
    $total = $prep->fetchColumn();        
    }

    echo "total: $total <br />";
```

VARIATION:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num_books from t_books where ". $_SESSION['where_field'] . " LIKE
 CONCAT('%',:search_term,'%')";
$prep = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$prep->bindParam(':search_term', $_SESSION['search_term'], PDO:: PARAM_STR);
$prep->execute(); 

if ($prep) {
    $total = $prep->fetchColumn();        
}
```

STRING QUOTE PROBLEM:  My initial attempts and the errors

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as num_books from t_books where '". $_SESSION['where_field'] ."' 
LIKE :search_term';  
Parse Error

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num_books from t_books where $_SESSION['where_field'] 
LIKE :search_term";
Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING'

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num_books from t_books where ". $_SESSION['where_field'] . " 
LIKE :search_term";
Notice: Undefined index: where_field
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  'LIKE '%the%'' 
at line 1

$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as num_books from t_books where ' . "$where_field" . 'LIKE :search_term';
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%the%'' at 
line 1
```

I am finding it hard to follow what is going on with the quotes.  Thank you for any course correction and insights you may give.

Comment: `"SELECT COUNT(*) as num_books from t_books where ". $_SESSION['where_field'] . " 
LIKE :search_term";`  That should be fine, but looking at your errors it looks like where_field isn't defined.  You should also look at binding the variables to the statement (though you can do it on execute as you have, this could get messy when you try to do multiple variables).  You have a code path above that results in where_field not being set, so set this as a default at the top of your code.

Comment: your third attempt is correct as far as the quotes but 'where_field' is undefined so you still end up with a sql error because it comes up as a blank variable

Comment: You're setting $_SESSION as `$_SESSION['$where_field']` - I think you mean `$_SESSION['where_field']`, as $where_field is a variable (and is undefined).

Comment: @andrewsi Thx for spotting that.  That explains Cfreak's comment to me.

Comment: @DaOgre Thx for the correct syntax and the suggestion.  Will work on the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num_books from t_books where " . $_SESSION['where_field'] . " LIKE :search_term";
```

Comment: Yes, this works but I had to define $_Session['where_field'].  I had several different spellings and so it was undefined.  A big thanks to you!

Answer (score 2):

it should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num_books 
       from t_books 
       where " . $_SESSION['where_field'] . " LIKE :search_term";
```

Comment: Yes, this works but I had to define $_Session['where_field'].  I had several different spellings and so it was undefined.  A big thanks!